# "bind" j to down (arrow) to scroll the document

Tags: javascript, scroll, keyboard-events, keydown

I'd like to basically give the behavior of the down arrow to the key `j`, so that it **scrolls the document**.

Here's what I've done:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.body.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    console.log(e.key, e.code, e.which);
  });

  const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    key: "ArrowDown",
    bubbles: true,
    code: 40,
    isTrusted: true,
    which: 40,
    charCode: 40,
    isComposing: true
  });
  document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

So, it fires the listener but doesn't scroll the document. It's really weird because when I actually press the down arrow, the listener is *also* triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The `dispatchEvent(event)` method will invoke EventListeners which you bind on the Dom .But it will not trigger the default behavior of browser.

Although you can trigger the `keydown` event by Javascript, doesn't mean that you can simulate press any key on the keyboard.

I think for some secure reason, there is noway to control user's keyboard through pure Javascript(Maybe some browser plugin can do this).

So , if you really want to scroll document when press `j`, i think you can try  this

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    console.log(e.key, e.code, e.which);
    if (e.which === 74) {// 'key j'
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {// scroll down smoothly
        setTimeout( function() {
          document.body.scrollTop += 1;
        }, 10*i);
      }
    }
  });
```

Hope this can help you.